# Deeplink to create branch from external site

Tags: azure-devops

I come from a Jira/Bitbucket environment where I could create a branch from within Jira. Bitbucket has a 'deeplink' that opens a dialog to create a branch:

http://[bitbucket]/plugins/servlet/create-branch?issueKey=[BugID]&issueType=Bug&issueSummary=[This+is+the+summary]

This allows an external app to call this URL (from a template) and start the 'create new branch' dialog in the browser. In this dialog the user can select the source repo / branch if other than default.

How can this be done in Azure DevOps?

In Azure DevOps wherever I click on the 'create branch' button it comes with a popup.