# How To Set A Default Template For Branch Names In Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

From a task on a board in Azure DevOps I can click on "Create a new branch" as shown below.

[image: Create a new branch link]

This will open a dialog in which to specify the name and base for the new branch. To save time — and to encourage consistent, meaningful branch naming on my team — I would like the name field to have a default based on the title of the task.

**Is there a setting for this or another way to accomplish the same?**

I've seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811118/deeplink-to-create-branch-from-external-site), but it remains unanswered at the time of posting. Also, if possible I would like to achieve this from within the AzureDevops online UI as that's how we currently track our work.

There is also: [Force a branch naming convention in Azure DevOps Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664386/force-a-branch-naming-convention-in-azure-devops-git). But I don't want to enforce the convention, but rather save time in using a convention we already consistently follow.

[image: Create a new branch dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a setting for this or another way to accomplish the same?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such setting to set the new branch name field based on the title of the task at this time.

We have to copy the task name and set it as new branch name manually.

Personally, this demand is reasonable. You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps:

[image]

When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For anyone looking to upvote it, the feature idea has been posted here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/749510/default-in-a-branch-name-when-creating-from-work-i.html